# Error reading Json array using foreach loop

Tags: json, foreach

I'm sending an serialize ajax post request.

```
$.ajax({
             type: 'post',
             url: 'js/json.php',
            data:{
                'a': 'JRNLHDR-SAVE',
                'formdata':$(_tr).find('[name^="formdata_jrnlhdr"]').serialize(),
                },
            success: function (data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (er){
                console.log(er);
            }
        });
```

Json data is correct

```
 Array
(
    [formdata_jrnlhdr] => Array
        (
            [153] => Array
                (
                    [txid] => 153
                    [reference] => PH/21/JB0161
                    [description] => Adjustment Entry
                )

        )

)
```

I'm trying to read the data in php but it giving an error

Undefined index: txid, reference and description

```
foreach($journal_entry as $keys  => $val){
  print_r( $val['txid'] . $val['reference'] . $val['description']  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That fault, because you miss your child array [153] .. and you call $keys in foreach, but still not using it.
Try this:

```
foreach($journal_entry as $val){
  print_r( $val[153]['txid'] . $val[153]['reference'] . $val[153]['description']  );
}
```

Edit...
For dynamic array index, use this:

```
foreach($journal_entry as $key  => $val){
  print_r( $val[$key]['txid'] . $val[$key]['reference'] . $val[$key]['description']  );
}
```

Comment: I have to consider posting an n number of array with dynamic array index. For each array set I have to parse the key values.

Comment: Then, try this one: 
`foreach($journal_entry as $keys  => $val){
  print_r( $val[$keys]['txid'] . $val[$keys]['reference'] . $val[$keys]['description']  );
}`